# How to check if a table is already constructed?

Tags: slick

Now I'm using Slick with Spray. I have to say Slick works much nicer alone, non-disturbingly with Spray than with Play (which is really troublesome).

However, I still can't solve a huge problem: database construction.

If there a way for me to maybe pass a list of `TableQuery` to a function, and it will match variables I passed in with tables in the database, and only create ones that are not created?

That would be really neat.

Assume I have two tables:

```
  val articles = TableQuery[ArticleTable]
  val users = TableQuery[UserTable]
```

I'm creating a function that may look like this:

```
   def createDatabase(list: List[TableQuery[*]]) {
      //.... (something like: (Article.articles.ddl ++ User.users.ddl).create)
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like someTableQuery.baseTableRow.tableName  should give you the table name. MTable.apply allows you to query for tables. Github search the slick code for examples of MTable.